# Element exceeds containing master element (ffmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to concat a group of videos using the following:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i ./vidlist.txt -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -r 30 ./out.mp4
```

But the command prints this to the console during the process:

```
[matroska,webm @ 0000018df0fd6a40] Element at 0x234559 ending at 0x234723 exceeds containing master element ending at 0x23454d
[matroska,webm @ 0000018df0fd6a40] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[matroska,webm @ 0000018df0fd6a40] Element at 0x300fa ending at 0x30111 exceeds containing master element ending at 0x300ee
[matroska,webm @ 0000018df0fd6a40] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
```

The video comes out looking fine, but the audio is occasionally missing for a small amount of time, so that short durations of the audio are skipped.

Comment: Looks like the input is malformed. Try with Matroska/WebM files from another source.

Comment: Are your output files working as well as your input files?  I get this error message, but the output files all seem to work the same as the input files (only with the new extension and codec).